# How can do uniformly (same sized checker boxes) of custom checkered texture image which applied on all objects of Model which loaded in Three Js?

Tags: three.js, geometry, mesh, 3d-model, buffer-geometry

I have loaded one model (obj file) in three js and applied custom checker texture image on all objects. Texture is applied on Model. But, issue is that - checker are not like uniformly - some checker are look small and some are look larger.

Here is [link](http://dev.4seating.com/sofaset/images/issue.png) of screenshot.

Is there any way to fix it ? I mean - any calculation on geometry or any in-built properties of texture etc. in three js.

Here is [link](http://dev.4seating.com/sofaset/obj/Model.obj) of model file Model.obj

loaded this model in three js and applied texture [image](http://dev.4seating.com/sofaset/textures/Chckers_1.jpg).

// Below some code which I have tried.

```
function loadModel() {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

        if (child.type.toLowerCase() == "mesh" && child.material) {

            if (child.material.length) {
                for (var i=0; i < child.material.length; i++) {
                    child.material[i].map = texture;
                    child.material[i].needsUpdate = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                child.material.map = texture;
                child.material.needsUpdate = true;
            }               
        }
    } );
    scene.add( object );
}

manager = new THREE.LoadingManager( loadModel );

manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

  console.log( item, loaded, total );
};

textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );

texture = textureLoader.load(currentTextureUrl); // texture checker image

texture.onUpdate = true;


function onProgress( xhr ) {

    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
        console.log( 'model ' + Math.round( percentComplete, 2 ) + '% downloaded' );
    }
}

                function onError() {}

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );


loader.load(modals.currentModal.objectFile, function ( obj ) {

 object = obj;                      
}, onProgress, onError );
```

Comment: it is not easy to do that through code. you would need to change the UV coordinates of the object, probably in a 3d model editor.

Comment: @gaitat , thanks for update. Actually, need solution by programming way. If you provide some guideline or logic concept, It should be better for me. 

Actually, I don't have much knowledge of three js. But, can implement if will get some logic.

we have lots of 3d models which was developed by third party. Here, my concern is that - if it will be possible by script (programming), why I have to change model. 

Also I just know - name of 3d model editor. but doesn't know how to create model and change its control.

Thanks,

Comment: you would need to create new UV entirely one that preservers area density ... that is very hard to do for arbitrary meshes